# ROS2 Distributed Nodes Not Communicating

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 - FOXY

I have setup two ROS2-Foxy environments with ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0:

1. RaspberryPi 3B+ Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit Server

- - Ubuntu ufw is disabled

2. VMware Fusion running Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit Desktop

- - ROS2 Foxy
- - on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit Desktop
- - in an 8 GB Ram 3-cores available to VMware Fusion virtual machine
- - on a 32GB 3.2GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 2018 MacMini
- - running macOS Big Sur 11.0.1
- - Bridged Network Adapter (same if Bridged Ethernet or Bridged WiFi)
- - Ubuntu ufw is disabled
- Each system will successfully communicate (localhost) for
  "T1: ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker" and
  "T2: ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener"
  (any combination of cpp/cpp, py/cpp, cpp/py, py/py )
- Each system is able to ping to the other
- Both systems ifconfig report

  UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST
- Multicast test works one way - to the VM

  ROS-VM: ros2 multicast recieve
  Waiting for UDP multicast datagram...
  Received from 10.0.0.11:43044: 'Hello World!'

  ROSbot: ros2 multicast recieve does not succeed
- Both systems have ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
- Both systems have ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0

**BUT** when I run a talker on one system and listener on the other, the listener never reports receiving the "Hello World" topic.

On RaspberryPi ROSbot running the talker, "ss -tulw" reports:

```
pi@ROSbot:~$ ss -tulw
Netid          State            Recv-Q           Send-Q                       Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port          Process          
icmp6          UNCONN           0                0                         *%wlan0:ipv6-icmp                                *:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                        0.0.0.0:7400                               0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                        0.0.0.0:7412                               0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                        0.0.0.0:7413                               0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                      127.0.0.1:58641                              0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                        0.0.0.0:34723                              0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                  127.0.0.53%lo:domain                             0.0.0.0:*                              
udp            UNCONN           0                0                10.0.0.11%wlan0:bootpc                             0.0.0.0:*                              
tcp            LISTEN           0                4096                   127.0.0.1:45585                              0.0.0.0:*                              
tcp            LISTEN           0                4096               127.0.0.53%lo:domain                             0.0.0.0:*                              
tcp            LISTEN           0                128                      0.0.0.0:ssh                                0.0.0.0:*                              
tcp            LISTEN           0                128                         [::]:ssh                                   [::]:*                              
tcp            LISTEN           0                100                          *:8888                                     *:*
```

and the ROS2 virtual machine reports:

```
ubuntu@rosdesk:~$ ss -tulw
Netid  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q                      Local Address:Port              Peer Address:Port  Process  
icmp6  UNCONN  0       0                                       *:ipv6-icmp                    *:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                               127.0.0.1:39592                  0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:60176                  0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:7400                   0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:7412                   0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:7413                   0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                           127.0.0.53%lo:domain                 0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:37045                  0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:631                    0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                 0.0.0.0:mdns                   0.0.0.0:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                    [::]:44486                     [::]:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0         [fe80::79:fbba:db15:6c00]%ens33:dhcpv6-client             [::]:*              
udp    UNCONN  0       0                                    [::]:mdns                      [::]:*              
tcp    LISTEN  0       4096                        127.0.0.53%lo:domain                 0.0.0.0:*              
tcp    LISTEN  0       5                               127.0.0.1:ipp                    0.0.0.0:*              
tcp    LISTEN  0       5                                   [::1]:ipp                       [::]:*
```

**Ideas to try?**

Update: It worked and then it didn't again:

**Well - when you need some magic, update everything on both systems!**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Voila:**

```
pi@ROSbot:~/rosbot-on-gopigo3$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
[INFO] [1625930607.244627442] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 9]
[INFO] [1625930608.245326225] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 10]
[INFO] [1625930609.245479175] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 11]
[INFO] [1625930610.244978271] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 12]
[INFO] [1625930611.245139866] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 13]
[INFO] [1625930612.245483542] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 14]

ubuntu@rosdesk:~/handsonros2$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
[INFO] [1625930576.490056884] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[INFO] [1625930577.489776977] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[INFO] [1625930578.489909352] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 3]
[INFO] [1625930579.489984629] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 4]
[INFO] [1625930580.489982903] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 5]
[INFO] [1625930581.490141665] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 6]
```

**Magic.**

## BUT WHAT DO YOU DO WHEN IT STOPS WORKING AGAIN AND NOTHING TO UPDATE?

**I guess I used up all my luck and magic.  Tried again today and it's back to no worky!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382133/ros2-distributed-nodes-not-communicating/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-07-09**:
Can you try running the multicast test as listed here: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#enable-multicast

I wonder if there is something in the VM network driver.

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-09**:
multicast worked one-way: to the VM only.

I performed the sudo ufw commands substituting my local net 10.0.0.0/4 not 224.0.0.0/4 - correct?
No change in send from VM no RX on ROSbot

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-07-09**:\

- aha, I think multicast should be
  working both ways on default RMW
  settings in foxy.
- That being said, try to modify your firewall for the 224* address like the guide says (there is something special about the 224* addresses https://superuser.com/a/441730)
- You may consider trying a different RMW like cyclone on both hosts https://github.com/ros2/rmw_cyclonedds#ros-2-rmw-for-eclipse-cyclone-dds (I know this helps when doing things in docker for me)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-09**:
Is the VM configured with a bridged network adaptor? Or a host-only? Or a NAT one?

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-11**:
Wow - hope and then hopes dashed.  @gvdhoom - tried both bridged ethernet and bridged WiFi - does not fix.

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-11**:
What should I check on WiFi router?  I'm wondering if something there is blocking DDS - it is strange that the multicast test works only one way.

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-11**:
Thought I had it by setting optional: false in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - booted 7 times with ping, ssh, and DDS success.  Went to celebrate.  Came back and couldn't ssh in first boot.  Too much to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, ROSbot Dave

has successfully booted up with full ssh, ping, arp, and ROS2 dynamic discovery Data Distribution System DDS working

- 12 out of 12 attempts
- since the change of 2.4GHz band WiFi access point
- - from the xFinity Technicolor CGM4331COM XB7 router
- - to my ancient DLink DIR-825 (last firmware released was 2013).

While I can say Carl and DeskPi have had fitful connections with the xFinity router(s), neither has shown the “cannot remote in” (ssh) issue that Dave exhibited, nor did I attempt distributed data messaging across the network when Carl was trying out ROS (1).

Carl has always been a Raspberry Pi 3B based GoPiGo3, but DeskPi was in fact using the exact Raspberry Pi 3B+ (plus) board that GoPiGo3 ROSbot Dave is running, except DeskPi has always run Raspbian/PiOS.

All these tests seem to point the finger at Ubuntu 20.04.2 on RaspberryPi 3B+ (or at least this particular 3B+) having unreliable ICMP, ARP, or UDP handling during the DHCP link establishment phase with the xFinity router configured with a reserved IPv4 address for the board’s WiFi MAC address.

I don’t know enough to be able to diagnose this deeper, and having found a solution that enables me to progress with my ROS2 learning (through migrating the “Hands On ROS for Robotic Programming” exercises), I am leaving this mystery of the universe unsolved.

I do have a new WiFi 6 router on order, (that has ongoing firmware update support), to minimize the chance my network will become a crypto-bot or participant in the next distributed denial of service attack on internet democracy.

**Calling this success - Onward with ROS2**

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0